# iOS 8: handling data returned from iTunes Search API

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using iTunes Search APIs to return the number of users that have reviewed my current app version. Since I haven't released the app yet, I have to handle the case where the iT search API returns nothing.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
 NSDictionary *iTunesDict = [NSJSONSerialization
 JSONObjectWithData:iTunesData options:0 error:&error];

 NSArray *resultCount = @[[iTunesDict valueForKey:@"resultCount"]];
 NSLog(@"%@", [resultCount objectAtIndex:0]);


       if ([resultCount objectAtIndex:0] == 0) {
           self.numberOfReviewers = @"0";

       } else {

         NSArray *reviewers = @[[[iTunesDict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"userRatingCountForCurrentVersion"]];

         if ([reviewers objectAtIndex:0] == nil) {
         self.numberOfReviewers = @"0";

         } else {
           NSString *howManyReviewed = [[[reviewers objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
           self.numberOfReviewers = howManyReviewed;
         }
```

My problem centers around the first `if` statement. Upon inspection, the value of...

`[resultCount objectAtIndex:0]` is: `(__NSCFNumber *)(long)0`

does not satisfy the condition in my first `if`.

**What do I need to make a **`(__NSCFNumber *)(long)0` **==** `0`**??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning the data as an `NSNumber` object. Use the `compare:` comparison function:

```
if ([resultCount[0] compare:@0] == NSOrderedSame) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

What this is doing is comparing the `resultCount` object to an `NSNumber` with the value of `0` (you can use the literal `@0` to short-hand an `NSNumber` as I've done above). `compare:` returns one of three values:

- `NSOrderedDescending`
- `NSOrderedSame`
- `NSOrderedAscending`

This reads from left to right. So if I was to use `NSOrderedDescending`, this would read logically "**is `0` smaller than `resultCount`**" (in descending order from left to right).

For further reading, check out the [**comparing NSNumber objects documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-SW12).

Alternatively, because you know it's a `long`, you can use the `longValue` method on NSNumber:

```
if ([resultCount longValue] == 0) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: You need to replace `resultCount` with `resultCount[0]`. `resultCount` in an `NSArray`.

Comment: So, referencing the way the web service is returning the data by casting (long) is this basically a simple NSNumber wrapper on a primitive data type?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. You can only place objects in an NSDictionary, that are derived from NSObject (NSDictionary, UIImage, NSString, etc...). An easy way to wrap a primitive data type in an NSNumber is to enclose it in @(), e.g. `@(1.567)`.